# Image Visualization - Styled Layer Descriptors - Sentinel 2

Tags: google-earth-engine, sld

I try user the Styled Layer Descriptors to SLDs ( https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/image_visualization ) for stretching pixel values to improve visualizations of continuous data in images Sentinel 2 but it doesn't work work. All pixels are converted to RGB (255, 255, 255), i.e., it is not stretching the data properly. Note that I am apply this visualization method to an image computed from the mean of an image collection.

[Code Editor script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/2bfc587e0010dae461cdeb1c44b7ef0c)

```js
var geometry =ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-56.78706327291917, -15.151036486409632],
          [-56.78706327291917, -15.216641306791784],
          [-56.70672574850511, -15.216641306791784],
          [-56.70672574850511, -15.151036486409632]]], null, false);

Map.centerObject(geometry);

var s2 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2")
  .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVERAGE_ASSESSMENT', 'less_than', 20)
  .filterBounds(geometry)
  .filterDate("2019-01-01","2019-12-31")
  .select('B11','B8','B4');

print('S2',s2);

var mean_reduce = s2.reduce(ee.Reducer.mean()).toUint16();
print('Mean_reduce: ',mean_reduce);

var vis_params = {
    'min': 600,
    'max': 3200,
    'bands': "B11_mean,B8_mean,B4_mean", 
    'gamma': [0.95, 1.1, 1],
    'region':geometry
};

Map.addLayer(mean_reduce.clip(geometry), vis_params, 'Sentinel 2');

var template_sld =
  '<RasterSymbolizer>' +
    '<ContrastEnhancement><_enhance_/></ContrastEnhancement>' +
    '<ChannelSelection>' +
      '<RedChannel>' +
        '<SourceChannelName>B11_mean</SourceChannelName>' +
      '</RedChannel>' +
      '<GreenChannel>' +
        '<SourceChannelName>B8_mean</SourceChannelName>' +
      '</GreenChannel>' +
      '<BlueChannel>' +
        '<SourceChannelName>B4_mean</SourceChannelName>' +
      '</BlueChannel>' +
    '</ChannelSelection>' +
  '</RasterSymbolizer>';

var equalize_sld  = template_sld.replace('_enhance_', 'Histogram');
var normalize_sld = template_sld.replace('_enhance_', 'Normalize');

Map.addLayer(mean_reduce.clip(geometry).sldStyle(normalize_sld), {}, 'Normalized' ,1);
Map.addLayer(mean_reduce.clip(geometry).sldStyle(equalize_sld) , {}, 'Equalized'  ,1);
```

Comment: please don't hide your code behind a link that requires a login

Comment: @IanTurton I've edited the question. I believe it is on topic given the google-earth-engine tag. Would you consider re-opening.

Comment: Yes, i consider re-opening. Thanks